# where should my game panels size information be stored in mvc design?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I am designing a server/client game based on java swing . I'm trying to use a mvc pattern . But i have a confusion about where some data are stored . I have some panels (here the are not JPanels or sth like that , they are just a window that show some information of game , for example life number) that i want to write their view part . Now the qustion is , where should i store some information like the panel width? Should the server send the panel width in the model it's sending? Or it should be handled in view part and client part ?
for example one of my panels model looks like this :

```
public class HeatLevelModel{
    int heatLevelPanelX , heatLevelPanelY , heatLevelPanelWidth , heatLevelPanelHeight;
    int heatLevelBarX , heatLevelBarY ,heatLevelBarWidth , heatLevelBarheight , currentHeatLevelWidth;
//getters and setters
}
```

Here its a panel that has a bar in it and the bar size is changing(like a health bar) . 
Is this a good work? Or should I have handled panel size with another solution ?
I know there is a problem here , that i am sending some constants over and over but having these constant in client from the start should not be the answer .

Comment: Gui layout is part of the view.

Comment: @c0der I know it is , but my view is in the client , and the relative size of GUI is saved in server (a class named Dimensions) . And I think the currect architecure is this that we keep these information in server isn't it? What should i do rather than this?